# Are you able to choose the starting tab for a TabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a method for choosing the starting tab for a `TabBarController`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In a view controller:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = n;
```

You can also set `selectedViewController`, if that is easier for you.